# Em um df, como selecionar itens em coluna com formato datetime, classifica-los em períodos (manhã, tarde e noite) e coloca-los em uma nova coluna

Tags: python, pandas, classificação, dataframe, comparação

Olá!!!  Estou em busca de ajuda para solução do problema abaixo.

Meu df tem uma coluna ‘DATA’  com formato 29/01/2019  17:50:11), que por padrão é convertida para 'objeto' do tipo pandas. Ao todo, ele tem 640 linhas.  já tentei muitas coisas, meu melhor avanço foi.

Criar um range para cada período e compara-los com os dados da coluna.

```
periodo1 = pd.date_range('2020-10-15 05:00','2021-03-18 12:00',freq='1T')
periodo2 = pd.date_range('2020-10-15 12:01','2021-03-18 18:00',freq='1T')
periodo3 = pd.date_range('2020-10-15 18:01','2021-03-18 04:59',freq='1T')

for index, row in df.iterrows( ):
     if row ['DATA1'] in periodo1:
        df.loc[index,'DATA1'] = 'Manhã'
    if row ['DATA1'] in periodo2:
        df.loc[index,'DATA1'] = ‘Tarde'
    if row ['DATA1'] in periodo3:
        df.loc[index,'DATA1'] = 'Noite'
```

A primeira parte no tocante a periodo1 o cod. roda perfeitamente. No entanto ele preenche DATA1 (nova coluna),  todos com ‘Manhã’ e  desconsidera o restante do código.

Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: A aspa simples no período tarde parece estar usando um encoding diferente, não sei se está assim no código ou apenas aqui no site, mas talvez seja isso. Se você copiou e colou o código aqui, vale a pena se atentar a isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siga os passos abaixo

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"DataString": ["29/01/2019 17:50:11", "29/01/2020 3:50:00", "29/01/2021 21:50:11"]})
>>> df
            DataString
0  29/01/2019 17:50:11
1   29/01/2020 3:50:00
2  29/01/2021 21:50:11
```

### Convertendo data string para tipo datetime

```
>>> df["Data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DataString"], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
>>> df
            DataString                Data
0  29/01/2019 17:50:11 2019-01-29 17:50:11
1   29/01/2020 3:50:00 2020-01-29 03:50:00
2  29/01/2021 21:50:11 2021-01-29 21:50:11
```

### Definindo função. (para determinar manhão, tarde e noite, só é preciso da hora, uma vez que a mensma está em formato 24h)

```
def categoriza(x):
    if x.hour in range(6, 13):
        return "manha"
    elif x.hour in range(12, 19):
        return "tarde"
    elif x.hour in range(18, 24):
        return "noite"
    elif x.hour in range(0, 6):
        return "madrugada"
```

### Aplica função

```
>>> df['categoria'] = df["Data"].apply(categoriza)

>>> df

            DataString                Data  categoria
0  29/01/2019 17:50:11 2019-01-29 17:50:11      tarde
1   29/01/2020 3:50:00 2020-01-29 03:50:00  madrugada
2  29/01/2021 21:50:11 2021-01-29 21:50:11      noite
```

**Nota** Vc pode ir sobrescrevendo as colunas. Somente fiz deste jeito para ficar mais didático

Comment: Paulo!! Caiu como uma luva. rodou perfeitamente. 1 abraço.

Comment: Opa! Não deixe de marcar a resposta como solução...